# Racket (Scheme) Error: expected the name of the symbol after the quote, but found a part

Tags: scheme, racket, the-little-schemer

I run this code (The Little Schemer) in Dr. Racket Verion 5.3.6:

```
(define rember
(lambda (a lat)
(cond
  ((null? lat) (quote ()))
  (else 
   (cond
     ((eq? (car lat) a) (cdr lat))
     (else (cons (car lat) (rember a (cdr lat)))))))))
```

and it throws the error: *`quote: expected the name of the symbol after the quote, but found a part`* in `(quote ()))` part. What is that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error indicates that you chose to run the program in the "Beginning Student" language. In this language the form `quote` is restricted.

If you change the language to "Beginning Student with List Abbreviations" everything runs smoothly.

Let's lookup `quote` in the documentation of the "Beginning Student" language:

[The form `quote` in Beginning Student](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html?q=beginning%20student#%28form._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-beginner..rkt%29._quote%29%29)

You will see that the syntax is described as `(syntax name)`.
If you compare this to the documentation of "Beginning Student with List Abbreviations" you will that `quote` now allows lists to be quoted.

The reason the Beginning Student language is restricted, is that only the form `(quote name)` is used in the beginning of HtDP, so if a student following HtDP writes `'(foo bar)` then it is not intentional. Therefore an error (stating that a name is expected) is helpful - consequently the `quote` form needs to be restricted.